# can i use my C1 visa transitting to japan

Tags: transit-visas, filipino-citizens

Im holding a philippine passport whith c1 visa (issued by US embassy) a transit visa that can transit to any airport in USA , can i use my C1 visa to transit to Japan or do i still need to get a transit visa to pass through their airport in japan? my last destination will be in Manila,Philipines. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is "C1" a kind of Japanese visa? If not, then which country issued the visa you're talking about?

Comment: C1-a visa issued by usa embassy to transit in USA, i have a connecting flight in japan but my final destination is in the Philippines.

Comment: Your ticket details please. Are they booked on the same itinerary? Does it involve changing of airports? What is the length of the connection?

Comment: @xuq01 , this is manny, from jfk to narita (3hrs layover) then to mnl (final destination).